# Violation of Einstein equivalence principle and Galileo Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, equivalence-principle, galilean-relativity

Two pulleys with one motor with the same force in each one. Between them a half strap or a rope which last sides is glued to each pulley. The force of the motors acts on opposite direction. Each motor shaft is conected to a heavy object to prevent the two pulleys from rolling up the strap. When we move one of the pulleys to the other one, the strap will roll up in it following its "natural motion" if it was not because there is another equal force acting in opposite direction on it, it will follow it.

This means we can know which pulley is moving to the other by looking in which one the strap is rolled in, therefore we can distinguish between reference frames, we can know if we are moving or not.

In a gravitational field things "go" to the floor meaning if we place this simple mechanism vertically, the pulley above will go to the pulley below, so the strap will roll up in the pulley above.
In an accelerated frame the floor goes to the things, meaning when the observer let or drop the pulley above, the one below will go at it, so the strap will roll up in the pulley below.
So if the strap rolls up in the pulley above you are in a gravitational field. If the strap rolls up in the pulley below you are in an accelerated frame.

This mechanism can distinguish the SEP scenarios, the EEP and the Galileo room in the ship.
I still did not any experiment and also i'm not an expert but this mechanism seem to work. I'm writting this here to see the opinion/answer of an expert.

This is a photo i drawn in paint. Also i'm using the translator because english is not my language and i'm not very good in it.

[image]

Comment: You have two identical motors/pulleys, etc., If you move them toward each other, there are frames where you can choose which is moving and which is still. It sounds like you would expect two observers walking alongside each pulley to disagree on which was rolling up the rope. Also, I do not understand why you don't expect both pulleys to roll up equal amounts of rope.

Comment: Is there a question you want to ask?

Comment: @JonCuster - "I'm writting this here to see the opinion/answer of an expert." He is asking if his idea is correct.

Comment: @mmesser314 Only one pulley will roll up the strap. As i said, in gravitational field the one above will roll up the strap and in an accelerated frame the one below will roll up the strap. It will be very helpful if someone confirms this to me.

Comment: In my comment, I meant an inertial frame. You said this could distinguish Galilean rooms in a ship. That was for what we would call inertial frames. I am trying to understand what you mean by "natural motion". But let me say that however you mean it, you have not discovered a flaw in physics. You have found that relativity is counter intuitive. The way the world really works is different from the way that classical physics works. Everyone finds It confusing and difficult to get right, especially at first.

Comment: @mmesser314 - which makes it off-topic generally speaking. Opinions and am-I-right questions are not a good fit.

Comment: @mmesser314 I didn't say i've discovered a flaw in physics. What i said is that the statement of "it's impossible to distinguish between a gravitational field and an accelerated frame" is not true. "Natural motion" means the strap would roll up in one of the pulleys if there is not another pulley with the same force acting on opposite direction. So if the strap don't go to the pulley, the pulley will go to the strap when we move it, making the pulley roll up in it.

Answer (score 2):

This mechanism cannot distinguish between an accelerated and a uniform gravitational reference frame. First, there are already far more sensitive experiments which have confirmed the equivalence principle to a high degree of accuracy. Second, you have mis-analyzed how such a device works.

Although not clearly specified, I am assuming that both motors are exerting the exact same torque and that torque is constant at all times. I am also assuming that both motors have the same mass and shape (same moment of inertia).

In the horizontal configuration, this results in an unstable equilibrium. Any slight perturbation to the system can have it begin rotating in one direction or the other. Once it is rotating in whichever arbitrary direction the perturbation produced, it will continue to rotate that direction as the torques are balanced.

In the vertical configuration, if the strap tension at the bottom motor is $T$ then the strap tension at the top motor is $T+mg$ where $m$ is the mass of the strap between the two motors. This larger tension at the top produces a consistent perturbation to the system in the "downwards" direction. Thus, the strap will always wrap around the "bottom" motor regardless of which motor is moved and regardless of whether it is under gravity or under acceleration.